# How to save accesstoken to string from API (C# Xamarin Studio)

Tags: c#, android, json, api, xamarin

I just started learning programming and I am currently trying out developing an android mobile application. I have watched a lot of tutorials and trying to find solutions online, but i can’t seem to get a hang of it. 
So i am now reaching out to you guys for some help.

I am working in Xamarin Studio, C#, and I am trying to create a loginsystem with the help of a REST API, and i am not really sure how i save the accesstoken to a string so that i can use it in further requests.

FILE: MainActivity.cs

---

```
namespace APItest
 { 
[Activity(Label = "APItest", MainLauncher = true)] 
public class MainActivity : Activity
 {
 private WebClient mClient; 
private Uri mUrl; 
private List<string> mItems; 
private ListView mListView;
  
`       public string acesstoken;` 
`       protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`
 `      {` 
`           base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);`
  
SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
mListView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.myListView); 
 
`           mClient = new WebClient();` 
`           mUrl = new Uri("http://...link.../login");` 
`           mClient.DownloadDataAsync(mUrl);`
  
mClient.Headers.Add("User", ”email@gmail.com"); 
mClient.Headers.Add("Pass", ”myPassword”; 
mClient.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
 mClient.Headers.Add("Accept", "application/json");
 
 accesstoken = mClient.Headers.Get(”Accesstoken").ToString();
  
`           mItems = new List<string>();` 
`           mItems.Add(accesstoken);`
 
            ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, Android.Resource.Layout.SimpleListItem1, mItems);
 `` 
 mListView.Adapter = adapter; 
       } 
 } 
 `}
```

---

In Postman API tool
(I send username and password in headers and receive following text)

```
{
"Result": {
”mRegister": {
"allowed": 0,
”Testmsg": "**"
},

`   …`

"token": ”EB9TEBINlVOASM0Ok04RlIjI8JGMVNVV1smFu5MT"
}
}
```

---

I know i have a lot to learn, but i would really appreciate your help so i can get started.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: what does you mean `save accesstoken to string`?  You have received the response json from server, I think you just need to get the token form the json string.

Comment: Thank you for your reply Mike! Okey i see, any idea how i get the token from the json string? I need the token to use it as header value for receiving other requests.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried:

```
accesstoken = mClient.Headers.Get("token").ToString();
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply John! Yes that is what i have right now in my code, but i get a null reference exception. I don't know if i might be missing a step after i add the username and password. It feels like i should have some code for it to sync (or something) first before it gets the token? because i dont get the token until i'am logged in.

Answer (score 0):

> Getting token form json string.

Using Newtonsoft.Json library, create your response Json object. And get the token string.

Following example show how to create a `User` json object to get the username and password:

```
using Newtonsoft.Json;

public class MainActivity : Activity
{
    protected override async void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        BlobCache.ApplicationName = "AkavacheText";
        string json = @"{ 'Username': 'Mike','Password': 'Ma'}"; 
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);
        var getData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<User>(json);
        System.Console.WriteLine(getData.Username+"---"+ getData.Password);
    }
 }

public class User
{
  public  string Username { get; set; }
  public string   Password { get; set; }
}
```

`string json` should be your response string.  `User` object should be your response object that structure depends on your json format.